# Knights Tour Java, knight must visit every square on chess board recusively atleast once

Tags: java, oop, recursion, knights-tour

Everytime i runt the program it wont make it past the 10th move because q always goes pass 9 which is my last case in the switch statement that makes moves sending it to the default. Please help does anyone know how I can control q so that it doesnt go pass 9 or if it does i can make the function do something else.

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
class KnightsTour
{

    int the_board[][] = new int[8][8];
    int moves = 0;
    int row = 0, column = 0; 
    int j =     1;
    int check; 
    final int backtrack = 9;
    boolean tour_found; 
    boolean isSafe;

    public KnightsTour()
    {   
    }
    /*recursive method, checks how many moves were made if 16 were made tour finished, 
    else if not moves knight checks if the move is valid if not back tracks*/
    public void findTour(int q)
    {
        while(moves != 64)
        {
            if(q > 8)
            {
                isSafe = false;
            }
            if(moves == 64){
                displayTour();
                return;
            }
            else
                if(moves < 64){ 
                    moves++;
                    System.out.println(moves + "\n" + "q:" +q);
                    move(q);
                    //displayTour();
                }

            if(isSafe == true)
            {
                if(q > 9)
                {   
                    findTour(0);

                }
                else findTour(++q);
            }
            else
                if(isSafe == false)
                {
                    moves--;
                    move(-q);
                }
        }
    }
    //used to keep prevent arrayindexoutofbounds error
    public boolean arrayInBounds(int x, int y)
    { 
        if(x < 8 && y < 8 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    /*move method uses switch statement to decide which move the knight should make
    based on a case number, negative case numbers back track knight. if statement checks
    if the current array element is empty and the index is inbounds*/
    public void move(int a)
    {
        int counter = 0, nextMove = 1;
        check = a;

        switch (check)
        {
        case 1:
            if(arrayInBounds(row+2, column+1) == true && the_board[row+2][column+1] <= 1){                              
                the_board[row+2][column+1]+= j;
                row = (row + 2);
                column = (column + 1);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (arrayInBounds(row+1, column+2) == true && the_board[row+1][column+2] <= 1)
            {  
                the_board[row+1][column+2]=j;
                row = (row+1);
                column = (column+2);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;

            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case 3:
            if(arrayInBounds(row-1, column+2) == true && the_board[row-1][column+2] <= 1){           
                the_board[row-1][column+2]+=j;
                row = (row-1);
                column = (column+2);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;  
        case 4:
            if (arrayInBounds(row-2, column+1) == true && the_board[row-2][column+1] <= 1){       
                the_board[row-2][column+1]+=j;
                row = (row-2);
                column = (column+1);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case 5:
            if(arrayInBounds(row-2, column-1) == true && the_board[row-2][column-1] <= 1){          
                the_board[row-2][column-1]+=j;
                row = (row-2);
                column = (column-1);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }           
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case 6:
            if(arrayInBounds(row-1, column-2) == true && the_board[row-1][column-2] <= 1){               
                the_board[row-1][column-2]+=j;
                row = (row-1);
                column = (column-2);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case 7:
            if(arrayInBounds(row+1, column-2) == true && the_board[row+1][column-2] <= 1){         
                the_board[row+1][column-2]+=j;
                row = (row+1);
                column = (column-2);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case 8:
            if(arrayInBounds(row+2, column-1) == true && the_board[row+2][column-1] <= 1){      
                the_board[row+2][column-1]+=j;
                row = (row+2);
                column = (column-1);
                j++;
                isSafe = true;
                break;
            }
            else isSafe = false;
            break;
        case -1:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){
                the_board[row-2][column-1]+= 0;
                row = (row - 2);
                column = (column - 1);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -2:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row-1][column-2]+=0;
                row = (row-1);
                column = (column-2);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -3:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row+1][column-2]+=0;
                row = (row+1);
                column = (column-2);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -4:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row+2][column-1]+=0;
                row = (row+2);
                column = (column-1);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -5:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row+2][column+1]+=0;
                row = (row+2);
                column = (column+1);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -6:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row+1][column+2]+=0;
                row = (row+1);
                column = (column+2);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -7:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row-1][column+2]+=0;
                row = (row-1);
                column = (column+2);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case -8:
            move(backtrack);
            if(isSafe == false){            
                the_board[row-2][column+1]+=0;
                row = (row-2);
                column = (column+1);
                j--;
                isSafe = true;
            }
            break;
        case backtrack:
            while(isSafe != true && counter != 7)
            {
                if(nextMove == check){
                    isSafe = false;
                    System.out.println("BACKTRACK12324");
                    nextMove++;
                }
                else
                    if(nextMove != check){
                        System.out.println("BACKTRACK");
                        displayTour();
                        move(nextMove);
                        nextMove++;
                        counter++;
                    }

            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No tour found");
            displayTour(); 
        }
    }
    //for loop to display tour once found//         
    public void displayTour()
    {
        String result = "";
        int v = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        {
            for (int e = 0; e < 8; e++) 
            {               
                if(v % 8 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(the_board[i][e] + "\t");
                    System.out.println("\n");
                } 
                else    
                    System.out.print(the_board[i][e] + "\t");
                v++;                
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Uhm... No need for `else` if you `return` ;)

Comment: Why don't you implement move behaviour in a separate `Move` class/interface with implementations/etc?

Comment: The Last else is missing the curly braces, is this intended? Format your code correctly! It is horrible to read this.

Comment: lol sorry I am new to asking question and hastily posted this, can someone run the program for me so they can actually see whats going on , project is a big part of my grade please11111